# PHP outputting incorrect date

Tags: php, html, forms, date

I have this code:

```
$date = substr($item[8], 7, 9);
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
```

At this point, $date contains:

```
12-21-12  <---- December 21, 2012
```

Now I am trying to output date into a input type="date" friendly format as such:

```
<input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)); ?>">
```

But it won't output properly.

If I change type="date" to type="text" I see the following output:

```
1969-12-31
```

Clearly something isn't working right in

```
date('m-d-Y', strtotime($date));
```

Can anyone help me clear up the problem?

Comment: From PHP docs for strtotime: To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Comment: I think, in addition to what you're seeing in the answers, you're also doing american-style dates with european-style hyphens: http://codepad.org/mcKrN6DH

Answer (score 2):

Dates must be in `Y-m-d` format, not `m-d-Y`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Nope, it's [in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value)

Comment: While it does answer the question, this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hold on, look at the code; it's being sent incorrectly to the browser: http://codepad.org/mcKrN6DH It may be misformatted by rule, but it's also outputted incorrectly to the `input`.

Comment: Jared is correct. By removing $date = str_replace('/', '-', $date); the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP 5.3+, I encourage using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

In your case:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-y', '12-21-12');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2012-12-21
```

As noted `strtotime('12-21-12')` because the date format is ambiguous in respect to the month and year.

Comment: I guess I don't have php 5.3 because $date won't echo anything.

Comment: @Jonathan, unfortunate. Take a look at `strptime()` as noted by **Matti**.

Comment: Well, the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) do say that this is the correct way to handle these date ambiguities. Removing the useless swap at the second line really [solves the issue](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), though.

Answer (score 0):

Removing

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
```

Solves the problem.